# Index GUI Issues with SSMS 2014 and 2016 when working with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms, ssms-2012, ssms-2014

We currently work with all versions of SQL Server from 2005 onwards. To save time I try to do everything in a single version of Management Studio. This also helps if running newer client operating systems like Windows 10 which old client tools aren't compatible with.

Specifically when trying to view the graphical SSMS interface for index properties I get the following error if connected to a SQL Server 2005 instance.

In Object Explorer:

```
Database > Table > Indexes > Right Click > Properties
```

[image]

Full error text:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Cannot read property IsSparse. This property is not available on SQL Server 2005. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

This also happens in SSMS 2014, but **not** SSMS 2012.

So my question is; can something be done to work around this issue allowing one version of management studio to be used for all versions of SQL Server from 2005 onwards?

I'm guessing now, but as it works in SSMS 2012 there must be something going on that targets an older version of mscorlib. Maybe because SSMS 2012 uses a VS2010 shell and different .Net framework?

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: SSMS 2016 is only documented as supported for managing 2008 and above ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)). This means they're not going to fix something that's broken with managing a version like 2005, which is no longer under any type of support. So, I would just keep an older copy of SSMS installed as well (you can have both) or just avoid any of the GUI wizards that cause trouble (many of them cause trouble anyway, even if "trouble" doesn't mean an error message).

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand yes the index GUI is fine from SSMS 2016 with a SQL 2008 instance. I guess the official line will be that SQL 2005 as a whole is no longer supported.

Comment: That's pretty much it, yup. Upgrade or keep two versions of the tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Active feedback about that on Microsoft Connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1307013/ssms-2014-displays-error-trying-to-view-index-properties-on-sql-2005-instance). Someone suggest a workaround to go into Table Design and go to menu "Indexes/Keys...". It works, but some properties are not editable that way, like Included Columns. The other options left are to use SSMS 2005-2012 or use T-SQL script, like Aaron said.